# How to change the default routing of a model at root in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to change the controller and action of `users` model in `routing.rb` when pointed at `/users` url. Here is how I tried to change it:

```
resources :users, only: :show do
    get 'favorites' => 'routers#client'
    get 'tours' => 'routers#client'
    get 'offers' => 'routers#client'
    get 'open_houses' => 'routers#client'
    get 'searches'
end
get 'users/:id' => 'routers#client'
```

The `favorties`, `tours`, `offers` and `open_houses` route to `routers_controller` `client` action when url such as `/users/:id/favorites` etc are called. But when calling the `/user/:id`, it doesn't map to `routers` controller. How should I change the index route to this controller?

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it through hit and trial. To route the index, we can do

```
resources :users, only: :show do
    get '' => 'routers#client'
    get 'favorites' => 'routers#client'
    get 'tours' => 'routers#client'
    get 'offers' => 'routers#client'
    get 'open_houses' => 'routers#client'
    get 'searches'
end
```